# Determine and classify the projective conics

Tags: projective-geometry

Determine and classify the projective conic that contain the points:

$\langle 0,0,1\rangle,\langle 0,1,1\rangle,\langle 1,0,1\rangle,\langle 1,1,1\rangle,\langle 1 / 2,2,1 \rangle$.

I used this projective conic equation but then I can't reach any conclusion:

F(x,y,z) = ax^2 +by^2 + cz^2 + dxy + exz + fyz

By substituting the values of the points I obtained the following equation:

-8fx^2 - fy^2 + 8fxz + fyz = 0

I can't develop further. How to resolve this?

I will probably have to calculate the projective extension, that is, solve the conic at infinity, when z=0. In this case I get an ellipse because x=y=z=0, that is, there are no points at infinity. Is that it?

Comment: Please show any partial work you have done, and explain where you got stuck. Showing your work will help users gauge where you are having problems, and you are more likely to get an answer. See [this guide on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Comment: Your last equation is the equation of a unique projective conic. You are done. "Classify" I am not sure what is meant by that.